# set 'always_populate_raw_post_data' to php ini of Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

Is there a way I could add or modify php ini that the Laravel used? I want to set 'always_populate_raw_post_data' to -1.

In my ajax base Laravel application, I have this warning.

> Deprecated: Automatically populating $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is deprecated
>   and will be removed in a future version. To avoid this warning set
>   'always_populate_raw_post_data' to '-1' in php.ini and use the
>   php://input stream instead. in Unknown on line 0

any help, ideas please?

PS: I'm on Laravel 5.2

Comment: I think you use php 5.6 probably, its an issue in this version !!

Comment: @Maraboc: yes so I'm looking a ways to touch Laravel built in php ini.

Comment: Do you use `Homestead` or local machine ?